# How to write nginx proxy pass for the Django application

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, django, proxypass

I have deployed a simple Django application in the AWS server and created a config file in the Nginx as follows.

```
                 server {
                         listen 80;
                         server_name 127.0.0.1;
                         location /portal {
                         include proxy_params;
                         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                           }
                        }
```

But it is not working and showing as "404 not found".

Django application alone working in a URL as **http://public_ip/en/** but I need to serve this application in **http://public_ip/portal**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configured this way, nginx appends the string `/portal` at the end of `proxy_pass` location, that is, your application receives URL `http://localhost:8000/portal` when you request `http://public_ip/portal`.

In order for `/portal` requests to reach `/en`, you need to use:

```
location /portal {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/en;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked

Comment: how can I add my static folder for the above config file? Currently, this file not detecting my  static folder

Comment: That is a separate question, please create a new question with the details of your configuration and file locations.

Comment: Added my new question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1053367/how-to-point-static-folder-in-nginx-for-a-django-application