# How to point static folder in Nginx for a Django application

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, django, proxypass, css

I have deployed a simple Django application in the AWS server and created a config file in the Nginx as follows. But its static files are not detecting.
Location of my static folder location: /path/static.

This application checks for static files by the URL  HTTP://public_ip/static, but I need to achieve the same in HTTP://public_ip/portal this URL

```
                  server {
                     listen 80;
                     server_name 127.0.0.1;
                     location /portal {
                     include proxy_params;
                     proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/en;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Please show the exact request you are making and what file it should return.

Comment: Sure, Application default checking URL is: HTTP://public_ip/static. but I need to achieve this in HTTP://public_ip/portal

Comment: And where the files are located it should return?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, this is my static file location is "/home/ubuntu/env/static".

Answer (score 1):

You need to have following `server` config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location ~ /portal(?<djangouri>.*) {
        alias /home/ubuntu/en/static;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @django;
    }

    location @django {
        include proxy_params;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/en$djangouri;
    }
}
```

First `location` block checks if a file exists in the path, and serves it. If no file exists, then request is passed to django.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Now I am getting this error in Nginx by adding the above config file. nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block

Comment: Ah yes, one needs to explicitly specify `proxy_pass` destination in the named location. Please try updated answer.